# Python Pandas ordering odd dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am learning some Python and have come across Pandas. I have an ordered dictionary that I want to use Pandas to output in a more readable format.

My ordered dict is a little weird, in that the format is as follows

```
{name:{Value1:float, Value2:float, Value3:string}}
```

where the name varies for each data input. Printing it using the standard python print function looks like this:

```
name1: {Value1:float1a, Value2:float1b, Value3:string}
name2: {Value1:float2a, Value2:float2b, Value3:string}
...etc
```

Which is then ordered by Value3, then Value2.

When i convert it to a DataFrame using lowdict as follows `df = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(ord_dict.items(), key=lambda x_y: (x_y[1]['Value3'], x_y[1][Value2])))` and then print(df) get the following output:

```
         nameA      nameB      nameC      ....
Value1   value1a    value1b    value1c    ...
Value2   value2a    value2b    value2c    ...
Value3   value3a    value3b    value3c    ...
```

My question is How do I use pandas to rearrange the DataFrame to look like this when printed?:

```
NAME    VALUE1     VALUE2     VALUE3    
nameA   value1a    value2a    value3a
nameB   value1b    value2b    value3b
... etc for 270+ values
```

I've tried pivoting the dataframe but not really sure how that works with an Ordered Dict like I have.

All help is much appreciated!

Cheers

Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict` with an `index` orient:

```
d = {
       'nameA': {'Value1': 1.0, 'Value2': 2.0, 'Value3': 'aaa'},
       'nameB': {'Value1': 3.0, 'Value2': 4.0, 'Value3': 'bbb'}
}

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')

       Value1  Value2 Value3
nameA     1.0     2.0    aaa
nameB     3.0     4.0    bbb
```

Comment: Wow, You back dude!!

Comment: @Wen For a little while, yes :)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @COLDSPEED.